# How to import an account into the NEAR wallet using only the private key (no seedphrase)

Tags: nearprotocol

In this post, I'll run through how you can import an account into the NEAR Wallet using only your private key. This is useful when you've created accounts (or sub-accounts) using the CLI or near-api-js and only have access to the private key.

To import the account, simply click this URL and replace the `YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID` and `YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY`.

- **testnet:**

https://wallet.testnet.near.org/auto-import-secret-key#YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID/YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY

- **mainnet:**

https://wallet.near.org/auto-import-secret-key#YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID/YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY

Comment: Thanks, it worked as a charm.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW you can find the source reference for this URL here https://github.com/near/near-wallet/blob/f6bc62abd7b28213b40ceb9d5371fe3b7a6a6b28/packages/frontend/src/components/Routing.js